# Laravel multi creation user

Tags: mysql, laravel, authentication

I need to create two users in the same time. Here is my code in the AuthController:

```
protected function create(array $data) {

    $profile = New \App\ClientDetail();
    $profile->s_firstname = $data['s_firstname'];
    $profile->s_surname = $data['s_surname'];
    $profile->p_firstname = $data['p_firstname'];
    $profile->p_surname = $data['p_surname'];
    $profile->s_mobile_number = $data['s_mob_number'];
    $profile->s_home_number = $data['s_home_number'];
    $profile->p_mobile_number = $data['p_mob_number'];
    $profile->p_home_number = $data['p_home_number'];
    [...all the form information fields]
    $profile->save();
   /*FIRST USER TO CREATE*/ 
    if($data['s_email']) {
        $user = User::create([
            'detail_id' => $profile->id,
            'email' => $data['s_email'],
            'password' => bcrypt('secret'),
        ]);
        $user->attachRole($student);
    }
   /*SECOND USER TO CREATE*/
    if($data['p_email']) {
        $user = User::create([
            'detail_id' => $profile->id,
            'email' => $data['p_email'],
            'password' => bcrypt('secret'),
        ]);
        $user->attachRole($parent);
    }

    return $user;
}
```

The problem is that the token is stored just for the last created user. In the mysql database, for the first user the column `remember_token` is `null`.

How is it possible to create two different tokens?
If you have an other best idea for creating two users at the same time, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the users like this:

```
$user = new User($data);
$user->save();
```

You have to declare the $fillable property in your User model:

```
protected $fillable = ['email','password', 'detail_id'];
```

Also you can use:

```
$user->profile()->associate($profile->id);
```

And in the User model:

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Profile');
}
```

Or you can do something like this:

```
$profile->users()->createMany($usersData);
```